# Specific Join of two Dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr

I have two data frames: `df1` and `df2`:

```
> df1

     ID  Gender      age      cd       evnt     scr     test_dt
1 C0004    MALE       22       1          1      82    7/3/2014
2 C0004    MALE       22       1          2      76    7/3/2014
3 C0005    MALE       22       1          3    1514    7/3/2014
4 C0005    MALE       23       2          1      81   11/3/2014
5 C0006    MALE       23       2          2      75   11/3/2014
6 C0006    MALE       23       2          3     878   11/3/2014
```

and,

```
> df2

     ID    hgt    wt     phys_dt
1 C0004     70   147   6/29/2015
2 C0004     70   157   6/27/2016
3 C0005     67   175   6/27/2016
4 C0005     65   171    7/2/2014
5 C0006     69   160   6/29/2015
6 C0006     64   143    7/2/2014
```

I want to join `df1` and `df2` in a way that yields the following data frame, call it `df3`:

```
> df3

     ID   Gender      age      cd       evnt     scr     hgt     wt
1 C0004     MALE       22       1          1      82      70    147
2 C0004     MALE       22       1          2      76      70    157
3 C0005     MALE       22       1          3    1514      67    175
4 C0005     MALE       23       2          1      81      65    171
5 C0006     MALE       23       2          2      75      69    160
6 C0006     MALE       23       2          3     878      64    143
```

I'm trying to add `df2$hgt` and `df2$wt` to the proper `ID` row. The tricky part is that I want to join `hgt` and `wt` to the `ID` row whose dates (`df1$test_dt` and `df2$phys_dt`) most closely align. I was thinking I could first sort the two data frames by `ID` then by their respective dates then try and join? I'm not quite sure how to approach this. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need  a rolling join

Comment: Are you sure the `hgt` and `wt` are not the opposite for `C0006`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to murge just matching the df1$ID and df2$ID, the following should do it:

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID" = "ID"))
```

if the date should be matched as well as the ID, you could try:

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID" = "ID", "test_dt" = "phys_dt"))
```

it is in the library(dplyr)